# svg border corners with inner border

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes

I have a some block, with some design:

[image]

And I have some svg code:

```css
.box {
 position: relative;
 margin: .75em auto 0;
 max-width: 255px;
 min-height: 56px;
}

svg {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%; height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>
 <svg>
  <mask id='m' fill='#fff'>
   <rect id='r' width='256' height='56'/>
   <circle id='c' r='10' fill='#000'/>
   <use xlink:href='#c' x='100%'/>
   <use xlink:href='#c' y='100%'/>
   <use xlink:href='#c' x='100%' y='100%'/>
  </mask>
  
  <mask id='m2' fill='#fff'>
   <rect id='r2' width='248' height='50' x="4" y="4" />
   <circle id='c2' r='14' fill='#000' stroke='#000'/>
   <use xlink:href='#c2' x='100%' />
   <use xlink:href='#c2' y='100%'/>
   <use xlink:href='#c2' x='100%' y='100%'/>
  </mask>
  
  <use xlink:href='#r' fill='red' mask='url(#m)'/>
  <use xlink:href='#r2' fill='none' stroke="#000" mask='url(#m2)'/>
 </svg>
</div>
```

**Question:** how to make inside a block with the same rounded cut corners, but not with a solid fill and stroke?

**P.S:** it should remain the ability to edit the radius of the rounding corners, indents vn. blocks. Perhaps there is a simple implementation on css (maximum cross-browser), would also be suitable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this?  It should work for any size by just changing the dimensions of `<div class="box">`.

```css
.box {
 position: relative;
 margin: .75em auto 0;
 width: 255px;
 height: 56px;
}

.box svg {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.size2 {
 width: 455px;
 height: 256px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%">
    <mask id="m" fill="#fff">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%"/>

      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="12"/>
      <circle r="16" fill="#000"/>
      <circle cx="100%" r="16" fill="#000"/>
      <circle cy="100%" r="16" fill="#000"/>
      <circle cx="100%" cy="100%" r="16" fill="#000"/>

      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="8"/>
      <circle r="14" fill="#fff"/>
      <circle cx="100%" r="14" fill="#fff"/>
      <circle cy="100%" r="14" fill="#fff"/>
      <circle cx="100%" cy="100%" r="14" fill="#fff"/>

      <circle r="10" fill="#000"/>
      <circle cx="100%" r="10" fill="#000"/>
      <circle cy="100%" r="10" fill="#000"/>
      <circle cx="100%" cy="100%" r="10" fill="#000"/>
    </mask>
  
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#m)"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: is there a way to include a kind of variable to adjust all the same value at once?

Comment: SVG2 lets you set the `r` using CSS. So you could use CSS variables and `calc()` , as in Afif's answer.. But, so far, only Chrome supports that part of SVG2.  Alternatively you could use Javascript to adjust all the radiuses and stroke widths.

Comment: your answer help me more than others https://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/BGJaVx, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I would go with a pure CSS solution using multiple background. It's a bit trick to manipulate but using some CSS variable you can make it easy to adjust:

```css
.box {
  --th:2px; /*thickness of the transparent part*/
  --l:4px; /*height of border*/
  --r:25px; /*radius*/
  
  
  --rad:transparent calc(103% - var(--th) - var(--l) - 1px), 
         #000 calc(103% - var(--th) - var(--l))  
              calc(103% - var(--th) - 1px),
         transparent calc(103% - var(--th)) 103%,
         #000 103%;
  --rad-s:var(--r) var(--r);
  --border:#000 calc(var(--l)),transparent calc(var(--l)),transparent calc(var(--l) + var(--th));
  --w:calc(100% - 2*var(--r) + 2*var(--th));
  --h:calc(var(--l) + var(--th));
  margin:10px;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:40px 20px;
  background:
    /*The 4 borders*/
    linear-gradient(to bottom,var(--border)) top   /var(--w) var(--h),
    linear-gradient(to top   ,var(--border)) bottom/var(--w) var(--h),
    linear-gradient(to right ,var(--border)) left  /var(--h) var(--w),
    linear-gradient(to left  ,var(--border)) right /var(--h) var(--w),
    /*The 4 corners */
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at top    right,var(--rad)) top    right/var(--rad-s),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at top    left ,var(--rad)) top    left /var(--rad-s),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom right,var(--rad)) bottom right/var(--rad-s),
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom left ,var(--rad)) bottom left /var(--rad-s),
    /*The main background*/
    linear-gradient(#000,#000) center/calc(100% - 2*var(--r)) calc(100% - 2*var(--h)),
    linear-gradient(#000,#000) center/calc(100% - 2*var(--h)) calc(100% - 2*var(--r));
    
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 
 color:#fff;
 text-align:center;
}

body {
 background:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  Some text inside
</div>

<div class="box" style="--th:3px;--r:20px">
  Some text inside
</div>

<div class="box" style="--th:4px;--r:40px;--l:8px">
  Some text inside
</div>

<div class="box" style="--th:5px;--r:30px">
  Some text inside
</div>

<div class="box" style="--th:1px;--r:15px;--l:3px">
  Some text inside
</div>
```

[image: CSS transparent inner border]

Comment: @HamSter yes ... check again, I added few pixel to correct this

Comment: https://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/mQqZvp?editors=0100 =)) ... hmmmm ....

Comment: @HamSter no not like that .. you need to adjust all the values, not only few of them  : https://jsfiddle.net/nb3ph59a/

Comment: @HamSter will try to edit to make it easier to adjust but yes SVG would be better if you find the good way

Comment: @HamSter made some edits, still not perfect but easier to handle now

Answer (score 2):

This is my answer: I'm using the size of the bounding box of the text so you can change the text as you like.
For the cut out corners I'm using arcs.
Also you can change the "padding" i.e. the distance between the text and the border.

```js
let bb = txt.getBBox();


function drawShape(path, padding){
let d = `M${bb.x},${bb.y - padding}
         L${bb.x + bb.width},${bb.y - padding}
A${padding}, ${padding} 0 0 0 ${bb.x + bb.width + padding},${bb.y}
         L${bb.x + bb.width + padding},${bb.y + bb.height}
A${padding}, ${padding} 0 0 0 ${bb.x + bb.width},${bb.y + bb.height + padding}
         L${bb.x},${bb.y + bb.height + padding}
A${padding}, ${padding} 0 0 0 ${bb.x  - padding},${bb.y + bb.height}
         L${bb.x  - padding},${bb.y}
A${padding}, ${padding} 0 0 0 ${bb.x},${bb.y - padding}z
`
path.setAttributeNS(null,"d",d)
}
drawShape(pth, 10);
drawShape(pth1, 10);
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 100">
  <path id="pth" fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" d="" />
  <path id="pth1" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" d="" />
  <text id="txt" fill="white" dominant-baseline="central" text-anchor="middle" x="100" y="50">
    some text inside
  </text>
  </svg>
```

Comment: If the inside border (white border) should be `1px` or `2px`, what should I change?

Comment: In the SVG you need to play with the `stroke-width` for the `#pth` and `#pth1`, keeping in mind that the black stroke (`#pth`) should be wider than the white stroke (`#pth1`).